# Every \newtcbox{\FOO} with a certain text-color?

Tags: color, tcolorbox

Imagine having a certain [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en) ([manual](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf)) named FOO, called for via:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\FOO}{colback=red,colframe=blue}

\begin{document}
\FOO{Something}
\FOO{Something else}
\end{document}
```

Now, is it possible to include something in the **Preamble** (i.e. before `\begin{document}`) such that every FOO will have e.g. green text?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `fontupper` like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\FOO}{colback=red,colframe=blue,fontupper=\color{green}}
\begin{document}
\FOO{Something}
\FOO{Something else}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are using `\tcblower` then there is also `\fontlower` which will apply to the lower part. Here you can use font changing commands (like `\sffamily`) too in addition to colour commands.

Equivalently you can use `colupper=green` and `collower=green`. 
There is also `coltext` which should be used as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\FOO}{colback=red,colframe=blue,coltext=green}
\begin{document}
\FOO{Something}
\FOO{Something else}
\end{document}
```

`coltext` is a short hand for using both `colupper` and `collower`.

Comment: You have answered perfectly, faster then SE allows me to accept your answer. Congratulations with your answer, which will be accepted in ±9 minutes. =) Your answer is as fast as a PING.

Comment: shouldn't it be coltext (or colupper) rather than fontupper ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Those are possiblities. I was still writing up. :-)

Comment: ``fontupper=\color{green}`` doesn't appear to survive page break, when used with option ``breakable``...?